# How can I use NSJSONSerialization with special characters like "ñ"?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsjsonserialization

I'm using NSJSONSerialization to parse Google suggestions.

The query "f" returns these suggestions:

```
["f",["facebook","flipkart","fox news","forever 21","friv","fandango","fedex","fitbit","food near me","flights"]]
```

The parser works fine but when there are special characters like "ñ" for the query "fac":

```
["fac",["facebook","facebook search","fac","facebook app","facebook lite","facebook login","facebook logo","facebook messenger","facetime","facebook en español"]]
```

It throws an exception:

> Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "Unable to convert data to string around character 139." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=Unable to convert data to string around character 139.}

Any ideas? I tried all different reading options but none of them works.

```
#pragma mark -

- (void)request:(NSString *)text
{
    NSMutableArray *items = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    NSString *query = [text stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters:[NSCharacterSet URLQueryAllowedCharacterSet]];

    NSString *languageCode = [[NSLocale preferredLanguages] firstObject];

    if (!languageCode) {

        languageCode = @"en";
    }

    NSString *URLString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://suggestqueries.google.com/complete/search?q=%@&client=firefox&hl=%@", query, languageCode];

    NSError *downloadError = nil;

    NSData *JSONData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:URLString] options:0 error:&downloadError];

    if (!downloadError && JSONData) {

        NSError *parseError = nil;

        id object = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:JSONData options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&parseError];

        if (!parseError && object) {

            if ([object isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]]) {

                NSArray *objects = (NSArray *)object;

                NSArray *texts = [objects objectAtIndex:1];

                for (NSString *text in texts) {

                    SNGoogleItem *item = [[SNGoogleItem alloc] initWithText:text];

                    [items addObject:item];
                }

                [_delegate google:self didRespondWithItems:items];
            }
            else {

                [_delegate google:self didRespondWithItems:items];
            }
        }
        else {

            [_delegate google:self didRespondWithItems:items];
        }
    }
    else {

        [_delegate google:self didRespondWithItems:items];
    }
}
```

Comment: this is not true. `JSONSerialization` can decode other encodings in JSON spec, [for more info](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/jsonserialization/1415493-jsonobject). are you sure you pass data encoded with one of these encodings?

Comment: of course it does, the string above can represented with UTF-16 as "ñ" is "0x00F1" with UTF-16

Comment: @Vulkan the point is to use `response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");`

Comment: I'm still missing the point as to what exactly I have to tweak to get it to work.

Answer (score 1):

`JSONSerialization` supports all the encodings in JSON spec, says [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/jsonserialization/1415493-jsonobject).

You didn't provide much info about the encoding scheme of your data but I guess you use `nonLossyASCII` or something like that, which is not supported by `JSONSerialization`.

Here is how I convert data to/from JSON:

```
let rawString = "[[\"facebook en español\"]]"
// if I use String.Encoding.nonLossyASCII below, I get the error you are getting
let data = rawString.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)
let dict = try! JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!)
let convertedData = try! JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: dict)
let convertedString = String(data: convertedData, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)!
// now convertedString contains "ñ" character
```

Comment: I do not know what encoding Google is using for its suggestions API.

Comment: remove "try!" and it is -almost- obj-c :) how do you convert response into a string?

Comment: My mistake. I didn't provide the actual code. Take a look at the main post again.

Comment: It works with greek characters and that was very promising because it took me a lot of time to get it work. Now, something else is broken.

Comment: [that](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsstring/1413576-stringencoding) may help to inspect the response data encoding

Comment: It's using NSWindowsCP1252StringEncoding, I updated the main post. It works now just fine.

Comment: glad it works but stackoverflow doesn't work that way. if none of the answers solves the issue, at least you should add your own answer instead of adding the solution into the question

Answer (score 0):

This will convert whatever encoding used to UTF8:

```
NSData *JSONData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:URLString] options:0 error:&downloadError];

NSString *convertedJSONString; BOOL usedLossyConversion;

[NSString stringEncodingForData:JSONData encodingOptions:0 convertedString:&convertedJSONString usedLossyConversion:&usedLossyConversion];

NSData *convertedJSONData = [convertedJSONString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Now, it works!